# Strange thing happening with modal input fields (Javascript / xhttprequestheader) writing to mysql but only for > 0 char in string?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, modal-dialog, laravel-8

I am using a Flashcards application from GitHub.
I am building this to learn Latin but decided to use existing code.
It works in Laravel and all good.
I added a Notes field to the application so it shows Front, Back and Notes.

BUT I am finding that when I edit and update the input fields in the model all good EXCEPT if there is no input left in the fields.  For any field with more than no characters I get the success message and look at mysql table and the information is there.  But with no character in any of the 3 input fields I do not get the success message and no change in mysql table.
This is what I receive back from a dd($card); in the controller update request:

```
Card {#240
  #fillable: array:3 [
    0 => "front"
    1 => "back"
    2 => "notes"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "cards"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:7 [
    "id" => 3493
    "created_at" => "2023-01-05 11:14:03"
    "updated_at" => "2023-01-07 05:01:20"
    "deck_id" => 1
    "front" => "Zdasdfsadf"
    "back" => "Zasdfsadf"
    "notes" => "Z"
  ]
  #original: array:7 [
    "id" => 3493
    "created_at" => "2023-01-05 11:14:03"
    "updated_at" => "2023-01-07 05:01:20"
    "deck_id" => 1
    "front" => "Zdasdfsadf"
    "back" => "Zasdfsadf"
    "notes" => "Zsdsfg"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

if a field is empty then I do not get anything back from the dd($card); in controller.
<COULD THIS BE RELATED TO THE ISSUE HERE:  https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/1816

The area I am looking at (I beleive is causing the problem within Laravel structure) is Javascript and code is below.  I.e. Controller is set up per link in Github below:

```
    function editCard(form){
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            //on success
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                flashMessage(this.responseText); 
                form.reset(); 
                toggleModalCard('modal-edit');
                updateCards();
                //now in updateCards()
                
              /*  document.getElementById('view-front').innerHTML = '';
                document.getElementById('view-back').innerHTML = '';
                delete document.getElementById('view-card').dataset.value;*/
            }
        };
        let data = "?"+"front="+form["front"].value     
        +"&"+"back="+form["back"].value
        +"&"+"notes="+form["notes"].value
        + "&" + "id=" + deck.id;
        let card_id = document.getElementById('view-card').dataset.value;
        xhttp.open('PUT','{!! route('cards.index')!!}'+`/${card_id}`+data, true);
        console.log(data)
        let token =  document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').content
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send();

The form is below:
    <div id="modal-edit" class="modal">
        {{ Form::open(array('onsubmit' => 'editCard(this); return false;', 'class' =>'modal-content')) }}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('front', 'Front') }}
                {{ Form::text('front', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Front']) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('back', 'Back') }}
                {{ Form::text('back', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Back']) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('notes', 'Notes') }}
             {{ Form::textarea('notes', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Notes']) }}
             </div>
            {{  Form::submit('Save changes', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
        {{  Form::close() }}
    </div>
    
        <div id="view-card" class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p id="view-front" class="card-text">
            </p>
            <hr>
            <p id="view-back" class="card-text">
            </p>
                <p id="view-notes" class="card-text">
            </p>
        </div>  
        <div id="editCard">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="toggleModalCard('modal-edit')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit card" onsubmit="if(this == ''){$this.val('empty');}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am stumped!
The original code which also does not work correctly is here:  https://github.com/Jondev01/flashcards
I tried to reach out to the programmer but no feedback.
Hope someone has seen this before and can make sense of this.

I try to get input fields with less than 2 characters to save to the mysql database.
< 2 does not save but 2 and > does.

Comment: Can you verify that the requests with less than 2 characters are getting through to your back-end? What happens if you `var_dump(<your_request>)` in your back-end file? If the requests are getting through, can you `echo` your query, and see its contents? If you can, and if the query looks fine, what happens when you try to execute that query manually (via phpMyAdmin, for example, or any other DB software tool)?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help:  This is what I output with the three fields with input that is accepted (i.e. from devtools in Chrome using console.log(data)): ??front=Zd&back=Z&notes=Zdd&id=1  This is also saved to the database.  Yet if I try to delete and of the fields (i.e. reduce the amount of characters from 1 to nothing for the notes input) the output is ?front=Zd&back=Z&notes=&id=1 and no message and nothing is changed or updated in the mysql database.  Its really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I solved my own problem.
I only needed to remove the following:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
/*    $this->validate($request, [
        'front' => 'required',
        'back' => 'required',
        'notes' => 'required',  
      ]);  
*/
```